# Matlab equivalent of `endsWith`: How to filter list of filenames regarding their extension?

Tags: python, regex, matlab

Is there a MATLAB equivalent of the `endswith` function available in Python, Java etc.?

I would like to filter a list of Strings by their endings, e.g. the list:

```
a.tif
b.jpg
c.doc
d.txt
e.tif
```

should be filtered by endswith('.tif') to result in:

```
a.tif
e.tif
```

Here's how I would do it in Python:

```py
textList = ['a.tif','b.jpg','c.doc','d.txt','e.tif'];
filteredList = filter(lambda x:x.endswith('.tif'), textList)
```

This is what I tried in MATLAB:

```
textList = {'a.tif'; 'b.jpg'; 'c.doc'; 'd.txt'; 'e.tif'};
found = strfind(textList, '.tif');
a = zeros(size(found)); for k = 1:size(found), a(k)=~isempty(found{k}); end;
textList(logical(a))
```

I might have to replace `strfind` by `regexp` to find occurences at the end of the string. In general, I think this is a rather complicated way of achieving the goal.
Is there an easier way to filter the list in MATLAB?

Comment: For this special purpose, use `fileparts` to get the file extension and `strcmpi` to compare it.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/matlabtools/source/browse/trunk/util/endswith.m. Just googled.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the hint using `fileparts`. I am getting the list from parsing a text file that contains also other text apart from file names. How can I use `fileparts` with the whole list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably quite efficient is to use regular expressions:

```matlab
filelist = {'a.tif'
            'c.doc'
            'd.txt'
            'e.tif'}

filtered = regexp( filelist ,'(\w*.txt$)|(\w*.doc$)','match')
filtered = [filtered{:}]
```

Explanation:

`(\w*.txt$)` will return all filenames `\w*` which end `$` with `.txt` and `(\w*.doc$)` will return all filenames `\w*` which end `$` with `.doc`. The `|` is just the logical operator.

Especially if you just want to filter for one file extension, it is really handy:

```matlab
fileExt = 'tif';
filtered = regexp( filelist ,['\w*.' fileExt '$'],'match')
filtered = [filtered{:}]
```

Filtering multiple file extensions is also possible, but you need to create a longer **regex**:

```matlab
fileExt = {'doc','txt'};
dupe = @(x) repmat({x},1,numel(fileExt))
filter = [dupe('(\w*.'); fileExt(:).'; dupe('$)'); dupe('|')] %'

filtered = regexp( filelist, [filter{1:end-1}], 'match')
filtered = [filtered{:}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `'match'` option was new to me.

Comment: @JanEglinger I added a version for multiple file extensions.