# How to find a 1-digit word using regular expression

Tags: matlab

I want to be able to detect a file by looking at its extension:

.m,
.fig,
.mdl,
.slx

but not

.mat

or others.

The final use will be to call DIR with a regular expression that filters out all the unnecessary files.

My first obstacle was to define a word of a single character "m". I couldn't figure out which expression should I use for REGEXP, and the documentation of Matlab was not clear enough.

An example of usage will be helpful, and a reference to a more understandable place will be very appreciated.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751842/list-all-files-in-a-directory-given-a-regular-expression-a-set-of-extensions

Comment: or see this [Matlab equivalent of \`endsWith\`: How to filter list of filenames regarding their extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121541/matlab-equivalent-of-endswith-how-to-filter-list-of-filenames-regarding-their)